# How to select directory for create a text file

Tags: javascript, c#, file

I need to select directory and i checked examples but i have something different `<input type='file'/>` is not a solution for me.

I want to open like File Dialog in my mvc application and select directory then keep that way and create a file in that way.

I have a example image for this

[image: openfiledialog]

Is there any way to do with JS/Html?

Any ideas?

Comment: @Praveen It's not a duplicate - it's simply not possible to create a file client side the way the OP intends to do.

Comment: @Filburt Ah... But something similar right? We can do that way... The one in the screenshot is our native file browser.

Comment: I don't want to create file in client side just i want to select one directory and keep that name @Filburt

Comment: @saulyasar so what about *"... and create a file in that way"*? Do you want the use the selected folder name and use it server side?

Comment: @Filburt oh sorry thats my fault but my idea is first open that dialog write file name  and get that directory so after i want to check that directory has file and create a new one i can do that in server side but i need to select and get directory way

Comment: @Filburt do you have any idea?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  my idea is first open that dialog write file name and get that directory so after i want to check that directory has file and create a new one i can do that in server side but i need to select and get directory way

Comment: @PraveenKumar do you have an idea?

Comment: @saulyasar You can't do it in client side. May be you can do it for your server files. You can't access client's computer from a browser. Not possible mate.